# searching words in file in python

Tags: python, file

I took an implementation of a function that getting this array: [key1, key2, key3]

My function need to check if all the keys are exist in file.

each line in file contain just one of the keys [not all of them]

I printed my function in order to check, and it seems that it's trying to search all the keys in each line [which of course always be FALSE]

please help me fix my function, many thanks:

```
def is_all_keys_in_file():
    with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
        key1 = '0\n'
        key2 = 'name'
        key3 = 'RecipeEndSucceeded'
        keys = [key1, key2, key3]
        counter = 0

        for line in file:
            for key in keys:
                if key in line:
                    counter += 1

    if counter == len(keys):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: For clarity, please show a fragment of the file. I think you're saying that each line in the file contains exactly one word/token

Comment: file contain three lines: 

first line : 0
second line: name
third line:  RecipeEndSucceeded

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I can help.

```
def run():
    found_keys = []
    filepath = r"C:\Users\Path_to_the_file\File.txt"
    keylist = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            for key in keylist:
                if key in line:
                    if key not in found_keys:
                        found_keys.append(key)
    found_all = True
    for key in keylist:
        if key not in found_keys:
            found_all = False
    print(found_all)
```

This filepath points to a text file with the following content:

```
Hello this is my testfile
0123
key3 I dont know
What
key2 whatever
should
key1 hm well
something 
foo
bar
```

For me, the `run()` function now prints `True` if all keys are found and `False` if not. But that of course depends on your file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that :

```python
from pathlib import Path
txt = Path('data.txt').read_text()
keys = [ '0\n', 'name', 'RecipeEndSucceeded']

print(all(key in txt for key in keys))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of scanning the file with loop, I defined three variables that each one reads a line in file and I checked if my key in array != from the line contant, it fixed my issue

```
def is_all_keys_in_file():
    with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
        key1 = '0\n'
        key2 = 'name'
        key3 = 'RecipeEndSucceeded'
        keys = [key1, key2, key3]

        status_index = metro_callback.readline()
        recipe_name = metro_callback.readline()
        metrology_status = metro_callback.readline()
        if status_index == key1 and recipe_name == key2 and metrology_status == key3:
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be passing the filename and list of keys as parameters to your function for reusability.

What you also want is the possibility of an "early" termination once (if) all keys have been observed. Another answer shows how you could use *all()* which is fine but is potentially inefficient for large files although it does make the code more concise.

Here's a step-by-step approach:

```
def is_all_keys_in_file(filename, keys):
    s = set(keys)
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in data:
            if len(s) == 0: # all keys have been observed
                break
            for key in s:
                if key in line:
                    s.remove(key)
                    break
    return len(s) == 0
```

Comment: Having the `keys` list as parameter means that it's defined "somewhere outside" the function. Modifying it this function might not be wanted. Also, removing elements from a list while iterating over it can lead to unexpected results, wouldn't recommend that. :)

Comment: @edg Take another look at the code. The remove is followed immediately by *break* and is therefore perfectly robust

Comment: you are absolutely right, my bad. I read the code too quickly, sorry again.